# How do I create an auto updateing sqlite table?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am using a python script to create and maintain an sqlite database for anime shows I watch to help me keep better track of them and the episodes I have and need to get.

I use the script to create a table for each series eg Bleach, Black Lagoon... and in each of these tables the following information is stored:

Series table:

```
Season_Num         # Unique season number
I_Have_Season      # yes or no to say I have a directory for that season
Season_Episodes    # Amount of episodes according to the TVDB that are in that season
Episodes_I_Have    # The numer of episodes I have for that season
```

the same table is created for every series I have and a row for each season in that series that seems to work fine.

Now what I'm trying to do is create a summary table which takes the information from the tables for each series and creates just 1 table with all the information I need it has the following information:

Summary table:

```
Series          # Unique Series name
Alt_Name        # Alternate name (The series name in english)
Special_Eps     # The amount of Special episodes (Season 0 in the series table)
Special_Eps_Me  # The number of Special Episodes I have
Tot_Ses         # The total count of the Seasons (excluding season 0)
Tot_Ses_Me      # The total count of Seasons that have yes in I_Have_Season column
Tot_Episodes    # Total Episodes excluding season 0 episodes
Tot_Eps_Me      # Total Episodes I have excluding season 0 episodes
```

I think what I want to do can be done using triggers but I am unsure how to implement them so that the summary table will automatically update if for example a new season is added to a series table or the values of a series table are changed.

**UPDATE:**

Fabian's idea for a view instead of a table after some more thaught and research sounds like it could be what i want but if it's possible i would like to keep each series seperate in its own table for updateing instead of haveing just 1 table with every series and every season mixed in.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have gone ahead and put in the triggers for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE i added them in the initial create loop of my script using variable's for the table names and the summary table appears to be updateing fine (after fixing how some of the values in it were calculated). I will test it further and hopefully it will keep working. Now i just need to get my script to add and delete tables for new series and for a series i delete.

Comment: Having one table for all series and seasons is proper normalization and avoids having to create/drop tables for new series. Why do you think that that is bad?

Comment: I don't think its bad i just thaught it was neater and easier to update if each series has its own table. @CL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved using triggers. But this kind of thing is usually better done declaratively, using a view:

For example,

```
create table series (
  series_name,
  alt_name,
  special_eps,
  special_eps_me,
  primary key(series_name)
);

create table seasons (
  series_name,
  season_num,         
  i_have_season, 
  episodes, 
  episodes_i_have,
  primary key (series_name,season_num),
  foreign key (series_name) references series (series_name),
  check (i_have_season in ('F','T'))
);

create view everything_with_counts as 
select series_name, 
       alt_name, 
       special_eps, 
       special_eps_me, 
       (select count(*) from seasons  where seasons.series_name = series.series_name) as tot_ses,
       (select count(*) from seasons  where seasons.series_name = series.series_name and i_have_season = 'T') as tot_ses_me,
       (select sum(episodes) from seasons where seasons.series_name = series.series_name) as tot_epsiodes,
       (select sum(episodes_i_have) from seasons where seasons.series_name = series.series_name and i_have_season = 'T') as tot_epsiodes_me
from series;
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to stick to the trigger design: Assuming you have your series tables like this:

```
create table series_a (
  season_num,         
  i_have_season, 
  episodes, 
  episodes_i_have
);

create table series_b (
  season_num,         
  i_have_season, 
  episodes, 
  episodes_i_have
);
```

and so on, and your summary table like this:

```
create table summary (
  series_name,
  alt_name,
  special_eps,
  special_eps_me,
  tot_ses,
  tot_ses_me,
  tot_episodes,
  tot_episodes_me,
  primary key(series_name));
```

You have to create three triggers (insert, update, delete) for each series table, e.g.:

```
  create trigger series_a_ins after insert on series_a 
  begin
    update summary set tot_ses = (select count(*) from series_a ),
                       tot_ses_me = (select count(*) from series_a  where  i_have_season = 'T'),
                       tot_episodes = (select sum(episodes) from series_a ),
                       tot_episodes_me = (select sum(episodes_i_have) from series_a where  i_have_season = 'T') 
    where series_name = 'a';
  end;

/* create trigger series_a_upd after update on series_a ... */
/* create trigger series_a_del after delete on series_a ... */
```

With this version, you have to add your summary entry manually in the summary table, and the counters get updated automatically afterwards when you modify your series_... tables.

You could use also INSERT OR REPLACE ([see documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)) to create summary entries on demand.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so just to make sure i understand in your answer i am not actualy creating a summary table i create a view and display it in a table? im not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Yes, you can use the view like a table in your queries. Unlike a table, the view does not store its content physically, instead it derives its content from the underlying tables when you need it. For the kind of task you want to do, this is usually the appropriate approach. You can do, for example, select * from everything_with_counts. When you add, for example, an entirely new series, you insert a row into the table series; if you add new seasons to a series, you add a row into the table seasons.

Comment: is it possible or do you know if its possible to do this while keeping the serie's in their own seperate tables? It would probably make updateing the series's and seasons episodes and such much easier though aswel if everything is in the one table? @Fabian Büttner.

Comment: That would be possible, but you would have to update the query definition every time you add a series. However, such a design is generally considered bad practice, since you would encode actual data (the existence of a series) into your schema (as table names). In general, a DB schema should not change when the data changes, only when you have do handle new kinds of data (logically speaking). EDIT: If you use triggers, you would have to update them every time you add a new series, too, in that table-per-series design (at least in sqlite, which does not support dynamic SQL in triggers).

Comment: ah so my idea of a table for each series is flawed for sqlite anyway. darn will have to modify my script then for adding and updating data and try your views strategy and see how i get on. was hopeing i wouldnt have to change my script after working so hard on it lol but thanks. @Fabian Büttner.

Comment: well, as I wrote in the beginning, you can do it with triggers if you want to. Then, you have to create three triggers (insert, update, delete) for each series table that you create. Each trigger needs to update your summary table. You woud have sub-subselects similar to the ones in the view definition in your update statement.

Comment: I have added a trigger version to the example, too.

Comment: the way my script works is it creates a series table fills it with the information then adds an entry to the summary table. so if i add a similar trigger to each table creation that should in theory keep the summary table updated? so when i update for example series_a table Episodes_I_Have it should link to or keep that entry in summary updated? @Fabian Büttner.

Comment: yes, that will keep the counters in sync. I don't understand the last past of your comment.

Comment: sorry i sometimes don't explain things properly. I was just basically trying to make sure i understood it. so if i add that or similar trigger and update an entry in series_a or add a new row to series_a it will be reflected in the summary table? @Fabian Büttner.

Comment: Yes. The three triggers (AFTER INSERT ON, AFTER UPDATE ON, and AFTER DELETE ON) on each of your series table will handle that (see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for the detailled syntax).

Comment: ok thanks can i add them from a python command? like for example:                                                        with con:
     cur = con.cursor()
     cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS series_a")

Comment: Yes, if you can issue DDL such as CREATE TABLE, you should be able to issue CREATE TRIGGER, too.